# subcategory is not show Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8

I've category and subcategory that subcategory is shown after moving mouse on ,I for accelerating speed of loading of my site have enabled the feature (use flat catalog category)But after enabling this feature subcategory will not be displayed when moving mouse on and in some pages the picture of category is not displayed,my Magento version in 1.8